# "Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled" error when trying to create custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, svd

I am trying to do SVD using a neural network. My input is a matrix (let's say 4x4 matrices only) and the output is a vector representing the decomposed form (given that the input is 4x4 this would be a 36 element vector with 16 elements for U, 4 elements for S, and 16 elements for V.T).

I am trying to define a custom loss function instead of using something like MSE on the decomposed form. So instead of comparing the 36 length vectors for loss, I want to compute the loss between the reconstructed matrices. So if `A = U * S * V.T` (actual) and `A' = U' * S' * V.T'` (predicted), I want to compute the loss between A and A'.

I am pretty new to tensorflow and keras, so I may be doing some naive things, but here is what I have so far. While the logic seems okay to me, I get a `TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.` I am not sure why this is the case and how to fix it? Also, do I need to flatten the output from the `reconstruct_matrix`, as I am currently doing, or should I just leave it as is?

```
# This function takes the decomposed matrix (vector of U, S, V.T)
# and reconstructs the original matrix

def reconstruct_matrix(decomposed_vector):
  example = decomposed_vector
  s = np.zeros((4,4))
  for en, i in enumerate(example[16:20]):
    s[en, en] = i
  u = example[:16].reshape(4,4)
  vt = example[20:].reshape(4,4)
  orig = np.matmul(u, s)
  orig = np.matmul(orig, vt)
  return orig.flatten() # Given that matrices are 4x4, this will be a length 16 vector

# Custom loss that essentially computes MSE on reconstructed matrices 

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    Y = reconstruct_matrix(y_true)
    Y_prime = reconstruct_matrix(y_pred)
    return K.mean(K.square(Y - Y_prime)) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_loss)
```

Note: My keras version is 2.2.4 and my tensorflow version is 1.14.0.

Comment: Tensorflow version? Always specify it when posting a question as this framework is changing paradigm even with minor releases.

Comment: Great point! My keras version is 2.2.4 and my tensorflow version is 1.14.0.

Answer (score 1):

In `tf1.x` eager execution is disabled by default (it's on for version `2` onwards).

You have to enable it by calling at the top of your script:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

This mode allows you to use Python-like abstractions for flow control (e.g. `if` statements and `for` loop you've been using in your code). If it's disabled you need to use Tensorflow functions ([`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) and [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) for `if` and `for` respectively).

More information about it [in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager).

BTW. I'm not sure about flatten, but remember your `y_true` and `y_pred` need the same shape and samples have to be respective to each other, if that's fulfilled you should be fine.